# usage of 'working graveyard'

Tags: word-usage

1. A graveyard is a place where dead people are buried.
2. A graveyard shift is a period of work that begins late at night and ends early in the morning.

I have heard some people use (1) above to mean (2). For example,

(A) I don't want to be a health care worker because sometimes I have to **work graveyard**.

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using "graveyard" as a short and informal version of "the graveyard shift" is very common, and 100% natural.

You can see from this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=work%20graveyard%2C%20work%20the%20graveyard%20shift&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) search that the short version is a less than half as common as the full one (and probably less if you filter out hits like, "work graveyard shifts"), but still significant:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.